# how to detect the bug of filter not working reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-state

Hi I click the "delete" button using `filter`to delete the data I do not need,but not working and there is no any bug notification,so I do not know how to detect out my project.

```
import ColorCards from "./ColorCards";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./initialState.json";

export default function CardsafterEvents() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(data.colors);
  const onRemove = (id) => setColors(colors.filter((color) => color.id !== id));

  return (
    <>
      <ColorCards handleDelete={onRemove} />
    </>
  );
}
```

full project link:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-62eh0?file=/CardsafterEvents.js:0-379

Comment: Where did you use the `colors` state? I don't see it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `colors` to your `ColorCards` element

- CardsafterEvents.js

```js
export default function CardsafterEvents() {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(data.colors);
  const onRemove = (id) => setColors(colors.filter((color) => color.id !== id));

  return (
    <>
      <ColorCards colors={colors} handleDelete={onRemove} />
    </>
  );
}
```

In your `ColorCards` element, not only use the data from `initialState`, also receive the `colors` prop from its parent, and use it prioritily with `useMemo`:

- ColorCards.js

```js
// ...
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import data from "./initialState.json";

export default function ColorCards({ colors, handleDelete = (f) => f }) {
  const dataColors = useMemo(() => colors || data.colors, [colors]);

  return (...);
}
```

Here's the [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-t146g?file=/ColorCards.js:77-116)